# Hide password from Msi log file

Tags: logging, command-line-interface, windows-installer, password-protection

I am stuck in a situation. When installer for one of our msi is executed from command line using msiexec command , the password gets displayed in log file.

I want to know if there is any solution to be used with windows command line to hide password. The command we are executing for msi debug is as follows:

msiexec /qn /L*v "AgentInst.log"  /i "Agent.msi" SERVER_HOSTNAME={IP for server} SERVER_PORT=9898 SERVICES_PASSWORD="{Password for services}"  START_AGENT=false ACCEPT_EULA=true

One solution is MsiHiddenProperties, but I don't know how to use that with windows command line.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can edit msi using Orca or modify installer project and append SERVICES_PASSWORD property name to MsiHiddenProperties property in Property table.

```
MsiHiddenProperties   SERVICES_PASSWORD
```